# How to get an attribute value from a href link in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the link from a "href" attribute:

```html
<a href="http://fgkzc.downloader.info/download.php?id=bc56585624bbaf29ebdd65d0248cb620" rel="nofollow" class="dl_link 1" style="">Download</a>
```

What I am doing:

```csharp
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lists1 = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("dl_link"));

string s = lists1[0].GetAttribute("a href");
```

I am getting the element with class "dl_link 1", but I can't get its link; the string is null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to call `GetAttribute()` with an actual attribute name. Replace:

```
lists1[0].GetAttribute("a href");
```

with:

```
lists1[0].GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 4):

**C#**

```csharp
element.GetAttribute("attribute name");
```

**Ruby**

```ruby
element.attribute("attribute name")
```

**Python**

```python
element.get_attribute("attribute name")
```

**Java**

```java
element.getAttribute("attribute name")
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, for anchor tags

```csharp
string url = lists1[0].Url();
```

will yield the same result as

```csharp
string url = ists1[0].GetAttribute("href");
```

**Note:**

Both return a complete URL even if the href has a relative path in the anchor tag.

For

```html
<a href="/profile/my-profile-id" />
```

it is:

```csharp
element.Url();
// returns http://mywebsite.com/profile/my-profile-id

element.GetAttribute("href");
// returns http://mywebsite.com/profile/my-profile-id
```