# C# innerhtml regex

Tags: c#, regex, selenium

Okay so I'm trying to extract particular data from innerhtml,

example of html -

```
<list class="bla">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=1&number=1" src2="http://www.example.com?id=1&number=1">
</list>
```

I'm currently using

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(innerHtml, @"id=(?<id>\d+)&amp;count=(?<count>\d+)"))
```

but this will get both ids&count from both srcs, how can i just target

```
src2=
```

for

```
id=&count=
```

instead of getting both

Comment: Try `@"\ssrc2=""[^""]*?\bid=(?<id>\d+)&(?:amp;)?count=(?<count>\d+)"`

Comment: What are you trying to extract as in `trying to extract particular data`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't work but url contians other random params & sub directors, example = http://www.example.com/imgs/ranbdom/balabla/img.gif?&bla=bla&id=1&number=1&example=example

Answer (score 0):

First, return your target attribute value with selenium, an example can be found
[how to get an attribute value from a href link in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620309/how-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-href-link-in-selenium)

Once you have done that use the following code:

```
string src2 = "http://www.example.com?id=1&number=1";
        Regex regex = new Regex("([0-9])");
        Match match = regex.Match(src2);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Basically, group 1 is where the first occurrence (id) of numeric value group 2 is the second occurrence of numeric (number) value.

More helpful links:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-groups 
https://regex101.com/