# Extraxt the name or href from a tag without click using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have tried to get the name or the href from a linktext but there was no way.

I was able to click on it, but not to get the name or href in a string;

```
var linkElems = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("  sorting_1"));
for (int i = 0; i < linkElems.Count; i++)
   {
        IWebElement tableElement2 = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(linkElems[i].Text.ToString()));
        tableElement2.Click();
   }
```

[Get the name or the href from a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FdYR.png)

```
<a href="#" name="42710962" alt="Click to open details in new window" onclick="window.open('/OTCS/llisapi.dll?func=ll&amp;objid=11743301&amp;objAction=RunReport&amp;SearchView=1&amp;PROCESSID=42710962&amp;ProjCode=0401-BIM','Document_Details','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=700px,height=600')">Architectura001</a>
```

Please is there a way to get the name or the href.

Comment: what is in your linkElems ? or perhaps if you can add complete html

Comment: <a href="#" name="42710962" alt="Click to open details in new window" onclick="window.open('/OTCS/llisapi.dll?func=ll&amp;objid=11743301&amp;objAction=RunReport&amp;SearchView=1&amp;PROCESSID=42710962&amp;ProjCode=0401-BIM','Document_Details','resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=700px,height=600')">Architectura001</a>

Comment: Yes, the same is in your question, I want to see the class sorting_1

Comment: That is a table containing links, where linkElems is the class in each row that contain the link.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Fuzq9h3

Comment: ok, so you just want the text ?

Comment: I want the text from the name="42710962" or the HREF

Comment: @FirasS I think you are trying to address a granular issue you are facing. However I feel we can address your _usecase_ with much simpler approach. Update the question with you exact _usecase_ (_Manual Steps_) and relevant HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get an attribute value from a href link in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620309/how-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-href-link-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to get text and then click it. The Link Text locator will do the trick automatically. Use below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(linkElems[i].ToString()));
```

edit

As you said you want an attribute value which can be found by

```
tableElement2.GetAttribute("name");
```

This will return 42710962

Comment: The above will return the text of the link